# Leaking diverter in shower valve

Tags: plumbing, shower, faucet

My tub faucet is leaking from inside the diverter control arm inlet ( little whole below the valve with yellow arrow).    Any idea if it can be fixed without replacing the whole unit?
The red arrow points to the stem that controls both hot and cold water.  I don't know the make and model as the trim plates markings have worn off.  The lever that controles  the shower head diverter just slides into the whole (yellow arrow) and controls the flow to the shower head by sliding to the left (off) or right(on)  the blue arrow points to the diverter control lever on the trim plate.  Don't know the make and model.
[image][image][image]

Answer (score 1):

There are seals inside the diverter which can be replaced. This may be an O-ring or a more complicated seal. Turn off the water at the valves. Unscrew the diverter stem and take it to a homestore or better to a plumbing supply.

Comment: Thank you kindly.  Is it safe to asume that the seals or o rings to the diverter are part of the valve stem?  The diverter is controled by a small lever that fits in the small whole at the bottom.

Comment: I was hasty and now realize that the leaking is not coming from the diverter stem but from some hole below the diverter. I cannot see the details in the picture. But this leak may be from a solder joint or a crack. Did you just solder this valve?

Comment: The shower diverter is controled by a lever that fits into the hole seen at the bottom of the unit (right below the shiny part) .  The leak is from inside that hole.  This unit is controlling both the hot and cold water with one faucet.

Comment: Is that Allen bolt unscrewed to get at the innards of the diverter? Or is that the actuator for the diverter? What is the make and model of the shower valve? If you look it up on Google it may show what are the diverter parts?

Comment: I've been trying to find a match to it since yesterday.  There is a two inch long metal rod that fits in the whole, and it controls the flow to the shower.  It just slides in and out, and it is being held in place by the trim plate.

Comment: The blue arrow points to it.

Comment: The closest i was able to come is a Symmons origins tub/shower unit.

Comment: Found it here.  https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01MUVSNK1/ref=sspa_mw_detail_2?psc=1

Comment: Not sure why the down vote reversed.  Good question with pics and explanations.